# Rails Get URL Path In View By Route Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Django template, I can use

```
 {% url 'pathname' p1 %}
```

to represent a defined path in url.py. e.g. above will show '/path/to/method/p1'.  Is there any method in Rails view (in .html.erb file) to do the same thing?

The "link_to" tag is not useful because it also generate the "<A>" html tag but I only need to get the path of url.

Thanks,

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you gone through [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) ? if not pls go through as it covers routing very well.

Coming to your question, rails has url helpers. 
So for example if your routes file has this route `get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'` then you could access this url like `patient_path(@patient)`.

You could also define its name like
`get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'`  where `as: patient` is the user defined name that could be used in the views to access this url like `patient_path`. You append `_path` to get the relative url.

Comment: this does not answer the question